# Docker selenium/node-chrome - Protractor can not find Chrome binary

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

I am a newbie to Docker, but not to E2E protractor. I am trying to build E2E integration out of docker containers.

Following [Angular's protractor cookbook using Docker](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/protractor-docker)

They have [Step 2 - Starting Selenium Nodes](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/protractor-docker#step-2---starting-the-selenium-nodes) with

`docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:latest`

I understand what Selnium Grid does - it allows browsers of different types to be tested by communicating with the grid.

When I have this docker container running Protactor does not use it as a chrome binary and I get `WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`.

How do I make protractor use this `node-chrome` container and not the local chrome binary?

My protractor config:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'mocha',
  directConnect: true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', // I have this set to the grid docker container from Angular cookbook
  specs: ['./stories/*.js'],
  onPrepare: function() {
    expect = require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised")).expect;
  },
  mochaOpts: {
    enableTimeouts: false,
    reporter: "spec",
    slow: 7000
  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}
```

This is how I run protractor on my headless server(non docker) `xvfb-run node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js`

Comment: Ideally you shouldnt see that error as Hub should pick up the chrom docker container. Can you try accessing the grid console `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`-  manually and see if the node is registered

Comment: Everything looks good for the hub. On the console page, I also see a chrome icon for `webdriver V` on the page. Here is the text output: http://dpaste.com/2JWB011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue... I removed `directConnect: true` in the protractor config and this allowed it to run without a local chrome binary. The solution is to make this `false` or remove it.

From docs:

> directConnect: true - Your test script communicates directly Chrome Driver or Firefox Driver, bypassing any Selenium Server. If this is true, settings for seleniumAddress and seleniumServerJar will be ignored. If you attempt to use a browser other than Chrome or Firefox an error will be thrown

Comment: I'm glad you found the "issue". The next version of Protractor should warn you if you have conflicting driver providers with the following pull request: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3873.